# Set Gmail label width

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Is there a way to increase the width of the left-side label menu in Gmail? Maybe with the help of some Greasemonkey script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Okay completely misread the question the first time. Let's try again!

This can be done using the [stylish extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) for firefox. Once installed (it's in the status bar) use it to write a new blank style. In the content area put:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain("mail.google.com") {

    .Bs.nH > tr > td.Bu:first-child > .nH { width: 250px !important; }

}
```

Obviously you can change 250px to however wide you want the labels menu. Save that and you should be good to go.

Comment: This CSS selector works as expected: .no > .nH:first-child

Comment: Perhaps we have a different gmail version. The selector you mention doesn't refer to the label menu for me.

Comment: Got the new version released yesterday. Anyway, got it working.

Comment: @desolat Good to hear. Also: the new gmail contacts is great!